# ExtJS - Saving nested data to .json file

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I created a store, where I'm loading nested data from .json file:

```
var userStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'User',
    storeId:'2013',
                autoLoad: true,
                pageSize: 4,
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url: 'data/users.json',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'users',
                        totalProperty: 'total'
                    },
                    writer: {
                        type: 'json'
                    }
                }
});
```

To add any new data to grid I use:

```
var asdfg = Ext.getStore(myNewGrid);
                        asdfg.add({lastname: nowa, firstname: nowa2);
```

Everything works fine until I refreshed the page. After it I lose all changes.

My model 'User' file:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Users', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

border: false,
views: [
        'user.List'
        ],
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'viewport > panel': {
            render: this.onPanelRendered
        }
    });
},

onPanelRendered: function() {
    console.log('The panel was rendered');
}});
```

Is it any simple way to save and commit my new changes similar to loading? To start my web use Sencha Cmd v.4.0.4

Answer (score 0):

just use `autoSync:true` in your *store*.

in that case adding `type:rest` to your *proxy* will make it easier.

look at this example: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/restful/restful.html

Comment: When I changed it as written by you it's not working for me yet. Is it required any commit or something? Content of .json is still the same like before.

Comment: `var userStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'User',
    storeId:'2013',
            autoSync:true,
                autoLoad: true,
                pageSize: 4,
                proxy: {
                    type: 'rest',
                    url: 'data/users.json',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'users',
                        totalProperty: 'total'
                    },
                    writer: {
                        type: 'json'
                    }
                }
});`

Comment: I wrote exactly as you but it still doesn't override the .json file.

Comment: I don't think write a file from extjs is possible. To change data you have to use server-side scripting such as rails, php, asp, etc.

Comment: Ok, so what we want to achieve your solution? Where the data will save if not to the file after autoSync? Sorry, I'm begginer - just like you can see. Please be understanding. I updated my post by Model's code.

Comment: In order to save data you need 2 more things:
1. **DataBase** - such as _MySQL_,_PostgreSQL_ or even _xml file_
2. **Web Server** to handle the connection to the db - such as _rails_, _php_, _asp_, etc.

for example, try ruby on rails and mysql, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6r_l3cAS9s) is an example for restful in rails.

**Its not going to be easy, you have to learn how to use it!**